# Divide big string in multiple small one - PHP

Tags: php, string

I am getting some long string from database and I need to parse it to don't have one big string but multiple one where each of them have 2 chars.

Let's make this on example:
I connect to table, get this string: `B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5` , after this i have to parse this string on pairs so:

```
B1 C1 F4 G6 H4 I7 J1 J8 L5 O6 P2 Q1 R6 T5 U8 V1 Z5
```

And do some cycle to insert something to it. (for example add random number at the end of this 2 char string and echo it after)

I was thinking about something like:

```
$string ="B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5";
$string1 = substr($string,0,2);
$string2 = substr($string,2,3);
```

But i beleiave there is some easier way how to do it, also my method is a problem when i don't know how long the string will be.

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: You can use a str_split() function to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for this:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/../', function($match) {
    return $match[0] . rand(0, 9);
}, $s);
```

It runs the function at every two characters and you can append a character of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5";
$newstring = implode(str_split($string, 2), ' ');
echo $newstring;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is my pick:

```
$string = 'B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5';
// let's find all the chunks of two chars
preg_match_all("/.{1,2}/", $string, $matches);
// there you go
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Sorry mate but your code throw error: Warning: preg_match_all(): Internal pcre_fullinfo() error -3 on line 4
NULL

Comment: Looks i was wrong, yea it works there i see it. You have a THUMB UP for that.

Is there a chance you can write me example with some cycle "to do" something with each "$matches", like for example insert it  somewhere or search in database for each of them...

Comment: @Andurit see Jack's answer above here for that. Besides that, you should probably be aware of `for`/`foreach` loops, what you with each entry of the array is up to you.